# How to give back true or false based on multiple criteria in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I have a data.table with entry and exit dates per individual and a text column indicating the reason for the exit. My data looks like this:

```
dt <- data.table (ID = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  entry = c("01/01/2010", "01/02/2016", "01/05/2010", "01/09/2013", "01/01/2010"),
                  exit = c("31/12/2010", "01/01/2021", "30/09/2010", "31/12/2015", "30/09/2010"),
                  text = c("a", NA, "c", NA, "b"),
                  result_2010 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,NA))

   ID    entry      exit     text    result_2010
1:  1 01/01/2010 31/12/2010    a          NA
2:  2 01/02/2016 01/01/2021 <NA>          NA
3:  3 01/05/2010 30/09/2010    c          NA
4:  4 01/09/2013 31/12/2015 <NA>          NA
5:  5 01/01/2010 30/09/2010    b          NA
```

In the column "result_2010" I would like to decide if the individual has left the company between 01.01.2010 and 31.12.2010, but only if in column "text" the individual has either "a" or "c". Otherwise the result should return "false".

The result should look something like this:

```
    ID   entry       exit   text    result_2010
1:  1 01/01/2010 31/12/2010    a        TRUE
2:  2 01/02/2016 01/01/2021 <NA>       FALSE
3:  3 01/05/2010 30/09/2010    c        TRUE
4:  4 01/09/2013 31/12/2015 <NA>       FALSE
5:  5 01/01/2010 30/09/2010    b       FALSE
```

Does anyone has an idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert the columns to `Date` class, and create a logical column based on the conditions in the OP's post

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
dt %>% 
   mutate(across(c(entry, exit), dmy)) %>% 
   mutate(result_2010 = entry >= as.Date('2010-01-01') & 
     exit <= as.Date("2010-12-31") & text %in% c("a", "c"))
```

-output

```
 ID      entry       exit text result_2010
1:  1 2010-01-01 2010-12-31    a        TRUE
2:  2 2016-02-01 2021-01-01 <NA>       FALSE
3:  3 2010-05-01 2010-09-30    c        TRUE
4:  4 2013-09-01 2015-12-31 <NA>       FALSE
5:  5 2010-01-01 2010-09-30    b       FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and for some reason when I run the code, the values in the entry and exit columns are deleted and I get a warning...

Comment: @Gabesz Is it based on the same example or not?

Comment: @Gabesz I checked again with your example and it is working fine for me

Comment: I tried it on my real data and for that it didn't work... I'll check again what could be the problem, thanks!

Comment: @Gabesz do you have `NA` elements in your entry, exit column in real data?

Comment: No, there are no NA elements

Comment: r2evans suggestion worked actually, so I could calculate the values for result_2010

Comment: @Gabesz My solution is based on your exaxmple posted and it works fine for me.

Comment: @Gabesz the issue is that when we use an exteernal function such as `between` it does some changes with respect to NA elements.  I posted the solution assuming that there are no NA elements

Answer (score 1):

### data.table

```r
dt[, c("entry","exit") := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), .SDcols = c("entry","exit")]
dt[, result_2010 := text %in% c("a", "c") & between(exit, as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2010-12-31"))]
#       ID      entry       exit   text result_2010
#    <num>     <Date>     <Date> <char>      <lgcl>
# 1:     1 2010-01-01 2010-12-31      a        TRUE
# 2:     2 2016-02-01 2021-01-01   <NA>       FALSE
# 3:     3 2010-05-01 2010-09-30      c        TRUE
# 4:     4 2013-09-01 2015-12-31   <NA>       FALSE
# 5:     5 2010-01-01 2010-09-30      b       FALSE
```

(Effectively a `data.table` version of the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69486310/3358272), and both benefit from the readability of `data.table::between` or `dplyr::between`.)